# Python3 - processing large lists: one class instance or creating new object for each element?

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory-management

this is more of a general Python performance question.

I created a simple class, which purpose is to:

1. get list of emails provided from user (in my case I use tkinter's GUI for input)
2. hash each mail using SHA256 algorithm
3. return hashed value

Code:

```
import re
from collections import Iterable
from hashlib import sha256


class HashData():
"""Creates SHA256 sums for iterable prepared for AdWords Customer Match"""

def __init__(self, data):
    if not isinstance(data, Iterable) or isinstance(data, str):
        raise TypeError('data must be iterable and not a string, {} provided'.format(type(data)))

    self.data = data

@staticmethod
def clean(value):
    """
    Prepares string for AdWords' Customer Match requirements:
    - no trailing spaces
    - lowercase
    :param value: str
    :return: str
    """
    if isinstance(value, str):
        return value.strip().lower()
    else:
        return value

def validate_email(self):
    """Validate if self.data is properly formatted email and raise ValueError if not"""

    pattern = re.compile(r"(^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$)")

    for mail in self.data:
        mail = HashData.clean(mail)

        if not pattern.match(mail):
            raise ValueError("'{}' doesn't seem to be a valid email!".format(mail))

def encrypt(self):
    """Creates generator for hashing self.data with SHA256 algorithm"""

    for row in self.data:
        value = HashData.clean(row)
        value = value.encode('UTF8')  # hashlib requires encoding before hashing

        yield sha256(value).hexdigest()
```

Source: https://github.com/dutkiewicz/adwords-customer-match-hasher/blob/master/hasher/HashData.py

I was worried about performance when user will provide large input, like 1 mln+ rows. Therefore I thought it'd be better to use a generator (self.encrypt()) which will lower memory usage. But at the same time I initialize object with full list, which could be huge :/

My question is what's better approach:

1. to load the input into one object and manipulate data?
2. or read the input one element at the time and create HashData() instance every time?

If my question is too vague, please let me know in the comments. This is a new problem I'm facing and I might not express myself in the best manner.

Comment: Loading data one by one is prone to add overhead (especially there are network connections in between). But getting a list in a paginated way can also fit, depending on the use case. For hashing throuh a list, you can use `map` with a [lambda function](https://medium.com/@happymishra66/lambda-map-and-filter-in-python-4935f248593).

Comment: Memory wise, 1M+ email addresses is not really a concern on non-constrained modern systems - even if you assume that the addresses are untypically large, say 256 bytes per address on average, that's _just_ ~256MB of memory. Collecting the hashes to return will even be smaller - at 32 bytes per hash you're adding only ~32MB of memory usage. At this scale, Python list overhead is negligible. In a world where simple web browsers routinely take many times more memory for basic operation, that's not really a concern. In general, memory is almost always cheaper than processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your example I have a different view of code in mind. 
I would have a problem strictly proving my view, but intuitvely `HashData` is not 
a great abstraction. It deals with a list/generator inside a class without describing 
the operations on list elements first. Your code repeats `for` loops  inside 
methods, which does not feel as a good sign.

`HashData` has the benefit of pooling your methods together, but looking at it 
from scratch it is basically a chain of operations on a list of stings. 
There is no state of object, several variables to hold together, 
or other things that are common to doing class os opposed to a function.

My view on your task is this:

a) you can have just a few "primitive" functions as below,

```
import re
from hashlib import sha256

PATTERN = re.compile(r"(^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$)")

def is_string(raw_string: str) -> bool:
    return isinstance(raw_string, str)

def clean(raw_string: str) -> str:
    return raw_string.strip().lower()

def is_email(text: str, pattern=PATTERN) -> bool:
    return pattern.match(text)

def encrypt(text: str):
    text = text.encode('UTF8')  # hashlib requires encoding before hashing
    return sha256(text).hexdigest()
```

b) You can chain the little fucntions them into a pipe of operations 
  as below or in some other fashion

```
email_list = ['gigantic@list1000.com', 'tons@ofemail.org'] * 100

# check type
gen = filter(is_string, email_list)
# cleanup
gen = map(clean, gen)
# filter
gen = filter(is_email, gen)
# encrypt
hash_list = list(map(encrypt, gen))
```

c) If you really want a class, I'd suggest creating something small and manageable like one below

```
class Address:
    def __init__(self, raw_string: str):
        if not is_string(raw_string):
            raise TypeError(raw_string)
        text = clean(raw_string)     
        if not is_email(text):   
            raise ValueError(text) 
        self._text = text           

    def email(self):
        return self._text

    def hash(self):
        return encrypt(self._text)

hash_list2 = [Address(s).hash() for s in email_list]

assert hash_list == hash_list2
```

Comment: Thanks! I was feeling that I'm overdoing it a bit :) I guess in this case using simple functions will work better than class.

Comment: @Dave - it is fine to explore! I actaully wrote some code similar to yours myself and from one angle it is ok, and can be done differently from another. Some people would actually want to assemble even a small number of functions to class, because they feel that way  the code seems more organised. A very helpful tutorial for me was [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wf-BqAjZb8M&t=755s) - it starts as a PEP8 review/discussion, butworks through a class to make it more readable, pythonic and better structured.